# How to set button loading text when form is being submitted?

Tags: javascript, meteor

I have a login form and I want the text of the `Sign in` button to change to `Signing in` when the form is being submitted.

What's the best way to do this ?

Example of what I'd like to achieve using the Meteor way : (loading state example)

http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#buttons

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is some boilerplate code that you can play around with :

HTML

```
<template name="myForm">
  <form>
    <button type="submit" disabled={{loading}}>
      {{! display different text based on a reactive helper}}
      {{#if loading}}
        Signing in...
      {{else}}
        Sign in
      {{/if}}
    </button>
  </form>
</template>
```

JS

```
Template.myForm.created=function(){
  // attach a reactive var to the template instance
  // you need to meteor add reactive-var first !
  this.loading=new ReactiveVar(false);
};

Template.myForm.helpers({
  loading:function(){
    // return the value of the reactive var attached to this template instance
    return Template.instance().loading.get();
  }
});

Template.myForm.events({
  "submit":function(event,template){
    // mandatory to prevent page refresh inherent to classic from submission
    event.preventDefault();
    // set loading var to true
    template.loading.set(true);
    // we use Meteor.loginWithPassword as an example, but you could use
    // any method call to the server here
    Meteor.loginWithPassword(...,function(error){
      // reset the reactive var even if the login failed (to allow retries)
      template.loading.set(false);
      //
      if(error){
        console.log(error);
        return;
      }
      // success code goes here
    });
  }
});
```

EDIT : added disabled state for the button for free.

Comment: Tips: use `disabled="{{loading}}"` instead of `{{disabled}}`.

Comment: Didn't realize that, thanks for the pro-tips :) https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/Using-Blaze#conditional-attributes-with-no-value-eg-checked-selected

Answer (score 0):

You can change the text of your button *on click event* of the Sign in. For Example:

```
$("#yourbuttonid").click(function() {
    $("#yourbuttonid").val("Signing in");
});
```